# Почему операция && вычисляется раньше чем ==

Tags: c++, операторы, стандарт, логические-выражения

```
bool f()
{
    cout << "helolo,world\n";
    return true;
};

int main()
{
    false && f() == true;
```

Почему не будет вызвана функция, если приоритет == выше чем у &&? С++

Comment: Тут дело не в приоритете операций, а в оптимизации. Если хотя бы один из операндов конъюнкции `false`, то остальные выражения нет смысла вычислять, результат будет `false`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Это не оптимизация!! Это - **стандарт** языка.

Comment: Скобки наше все! Чтобы самому не запутаться в приоритете операций (и не запутать коллег) в любой непонятной ситуации следует юзать скобки

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, в данном выражении скобки ничего не изменят. В какое место вставить скобки, чтобы функция вызывалась?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan так если задача в том, чтобы функция была обязательно вызвана, то ее и ставить нужно на первое место. Скобки, как раз таки, это прекрасным образом демонстрируют - то есть их нельзя вставить в выражение таким образом, чтобы оно работало, поскольку выражение, в текущем виде, не верно.

Comment: И вообще, если надо, чтоб обе части работали - что-то типа `if(bool a = f(), b= g(); a&&b) { ...`

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch,  почему то я решил написать ответ после вашего комментария...

Answer (score 10):

Потому что есть правило сокращенных вычислений логических выражений.

Если уже понятно, что результат будет `false` - а иным при операции `&&` и первом аргументе `false` он быть не может - вторая часть не вычисляется вовсе.

Для `||` - то же самое, если первая часть вычислена как `true`.

Очень удобно - например,

```
if (p && *p == 0) ...
```

Если `p` - нулевой указатель, разыменования не будет.

Грубо говоря,

```
if (a && b) {
```

превращается в

```
if (a) {
    if (b) {
```

Из **стандарта**:

> 7.6.14 Logical AND operator [expr.log.and]
>
> 1 The && operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to bool (7.3). The result is true if both operands are true and false otherwise. Unlike &, **&& guarantees left-to-right evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is false**.
>
> 7.6.15 Logical OR operator [expr.log.or]
>
> 1 The || operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to bool (7.3). The result is true if either of its operands is true, and false otherwise. Unlike |, **|| guarantees left-to-right evaluation; moreover, the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand evaluates to true**.

Comment: Про такую оптимизацию я знаю, но, на мой взгляд, она противоречит собственным правилам приоритета вычисления операций. Почему нельзя изменить приоритеты этих операций, чтобы не было противоречия

Comment: Это НЕ оптимизация, это **СТАНДАРТ** языка. См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: @АндрейКирин Здесь нет противоречия. Приоритеты применяются к тем выражениям, которые вычисляются. А правила сокращенных вычислений логических выражений говорят, что должно вычисляться. То есть сначала определяется, нужно ли вообще вычислять, и только если нужно - начинается разбор приоритетов.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов последнее предложение не совсем так -- сначала, во время компиляции, вычисляются приоритеты и ассоциативность `(false) && ((f()) == true)` left to right, а потом, уже в рантайме, решается, что правое выражение можно не вычислять. Конечно, компилятор волен соптимизировать до `false` и ничего в рантайме не рассматривать вообще, но концептуально приоритеты разбираются до выяснения нужности вычисления. Ведь если не задано порядка/приоритетов, то нужность вычисления чего определять?

Answer (score 2):

Если есть сомнения, поставьте скобки в разных местах выражения(подсказка от Andrej Levkovitch ):

1. `(false && f()) == true;`

левая часть выдаст `false` и не будет проверена правая часть выражения в скобках, останется проверять еще  выражение `false == true`(лишняя операция)

2. `false && (f() == true);`

так как левая часть `false`, не будет проверяться правая часть, т.е. `false && (`выражение не вычисляется`)`  имеет результат  `false`.

А значит второй вариант все таки получше первого,  хотя и результат одинаков, если слева оператора `&&`, есть ложь. Так что ставить скобки не всегда  есть хорошо...

Comment: Не очень понял, честно говоря, доказываемый тезис. Вопрос о приоритете операторов же вроде как не стоит? Вернее, поставлен ошибочно - ТС решил, что здесь нарушено правило приоритетов (мол, приоритет == выше), но он просто неверно его применил...

Comment: @Harry, доказываемый тезис, просто есть дополнительная информация, но ставив скобки,  автор мог и сам убедиться, что приоритет операции не имеет значения(в данном случаи)

Answer (score -2):

Булева логика такова, что проверяется слева направо. У вас первый операнд равен False, далее идёт оператор &&. Этот оператор подразумевает, если операнд слева равен False, то последущие операнды не будут проверяться, т.к это не имеет смысла, т.к всё выражение всё равно будет равно False. Если хотите чтобы функция выполнилась нужно использовать одиночный оператор &.

```
if(false & f() == true) // условие будет ложным, но функция f() будет вызвана
```

Comment: −1. Вы вкурсе, что `&` — это побитовое И?

Comment: прежде чем отправить комментарий, убедитесь, не будут ли все смеяться над ним)